# \B+ vs [\B]+ vs [^\b]+ in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I ran across an issue I don't understand while answering an SO question.  I've created a simplified example to illustrate the problem:

**THE SCENARIO:**

I'm testing that two tokens (not random English words!) are at least some distance apart in a string.  In this example we have a list of animals and we want to make sure there are at least three other animals between the sheep and the wolf (or there'll be trouble).  The following code works:

```
import re

safe_distance = re.compile(r"sheep (\b[^\b]+\b ){3,}wolf")

animal_arrangements = [
    "dog sheep hen wolf fox cat ox",  # one between
    "dog sheep hen fox wolf cat ox",  # two between
    "dog sheep hen fox cat wolf ox",  # three between
    "dog sheep hen fox cat ox wolf"   # four between
]

for i, animal_arrangement in enumerate(animal_arrangements):

    if safe_distance.search(animal_arrangement):
        print(i + 1, "All is peaceful.")
    else:
        print(i + 1, "Sheep and wolf too close!")
```

**THE QUESTION:**

In the above pattern, using:

```
[^\b]+  # works fine
\B+     # causes a regex compilation error "nothing to repeat"
[\B]+   # runs but produces wrong answers
\w+     # yes, this does work, probably best, but not related to my question
```

Why the difference?  I don't need a better solution to the sheep/wolf placement problem -- I'm just trying to understand why these three variants of *one-or-more-not-a-word-boundary* patterns produce different results.

I know `\b`, like an anchor, doesn't represent a character and the patten is ill-considered (compared to using `\w') but again, why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\B+` pattern causes nothing to repeat error that is a usual error when you try to *quantify a special regex operator that is a zero-width assertion*. Any of these - `(*`, `|*`, `\b+`, `\B+` - will cause this error. Repeating a zero-width assertion makes no sense as it does not consume any characters and the regex index remains at the same position. Note that `a{1,2}+` and `f*+` (possessive quantifiers that Python `re` does not support) cause another, but similar error - *multiple repeat*.

Now, the `\b` and `\B` cannot be used inside a character class. See [`re` Python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Note that `\b` is used to represent word boundaries, and means “backspace” only inside character classes.
>   ...
>   Inside a character range, `\b` represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.

Also, FYI,

> `\number`
>   ... Inside the `[` and `]` of a character class, all numeric escapes are treated as characters.

In the same way, you cannot use `\B`, `\A`, `\Z` and *backreferences* like `\1` inside *character classes*. They just lose their special regex meaning and are treated as whatever Python sees right. Actually, since Python parses invalid escape sequences as `\` + char, the **`[\B]` matches only `B` char, since `\` is escaping a literal symbol and the symbol is matched as such**. Thus,

```
print(re.findall(r'[\B]+', "BBB \\Bash"))
```

[outputs `['BBB', 'B']` only](http://ideone.com/4HaYkz).

And `r"[^\b]+"` only matches all chars that are not a backspace char:

```
print(re.findall(r'[^\b]+', "bbb \\bash\baaa"))
```

outputs [`['bbb \\bash', 'aaa']`](http://ideone.com/wCihS4).

Comment: I'd gladly mark your answer accepted if you don't mind dropping the introductory part about \w, etc. as their preferabilty, and my wish that answers not try to improve upon the sheep/wolf algorithm, was covered in my question.  Your discussion of the issue of `[\B]+` and variants is excellent.  My hidden agenda was to show one can mistakenly extrapolate from `\D+`, `[\D]+` and `[^\d]+` which are all valid and synonyms to what I did with `\B+' and have it go wrong (including a case that appears to do what I want but really doesn't and could easily hide in "working" code.)

Comment: I removed the suggestion at the beginning. Actually, the zero-width shorthands inside character classes lose their special meaning. `[\d]` and `[\s]` and `[\w]` are consuming shorthands inside character classes, and they are supported in Python (and most other) character classes.

Comment: In Java and .NET, `[\B]`, `[\A]`, etc. are treated as a syntax error, same as non-existent escapes like `\j`.  I think that's a better approach; anyone using `[\B]` on purpose is probably in need of some remedial feedback.  I'd like to see `[\b]` and `[^\b]` treated as an error, too.  Has anyone **ever** needed to match or exclude the backspace character specifically?  That's a case of the tail wagging the dog if I ever saw one!

Comment: @AlanMoore: Python `re` module is rather specific, a lot of things just does not work as in other regex flavors, e.g. `\Z` in Python is the same as `\z` in Java and .NET regex. You can use `[\w-\s]` in .NET, but in Python the `-` will be treated as a range operator (error: `bad character range`). I think Python authors wanted to make the `re` module smarter than it needs to be :)

Answer (score 3):

- `\B+` causes an error because there's no point in repeating a boundary - one boundary is the same as two boundaries. It's more likely that you've done this by mistake, so the error makes sense.
- `[\B]+` is something completely different. (Most) Escape sequences do not work inside a character class, which is why this is a character set that matches the character `\` or `B`, so obviously repeating this is possible.

Comment: Good call, upon testing, [\B]+ does match repeated B's -- though I can't make it match \'s so that part of your analysis might not be right.

Comment: Extending your reasoning, `[^\b]+` should match one or not 'b', i.e. the same as `[^b]+` but that's not what actually happens as `re.search(r"[^\b]+", "bbb")` and `re.search(r"[^b]+", "bbb")` produce different results.

Comment: @cdlane `\b` (inside square brackets) should be the literal backspace character.

Comment: Your `\B+` explanation is consistent with `\b+` and makes sense.  +1 for two out of three!

Comment: Thanks @SebastianProske, that checks out, you've nailed down the third variant! +1